# GitHub Markdown Mode

Tags: markdown, github

Is there an Emacs mode for GitHub Flavored Markdown?

GitHub Flavored Markdown [adds a number of features](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) to traditional Markdown: underscore handling, url autolinking, strikethrough, and tables. It would be nice to have an Emacs mode that supports these additions (particularly tables).

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4276/2355

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's `gfm-mode` (which is part of [markdown-mode.el](http://melpa.org/#/markdown-mode)). From the commentary in the file:

```
;;; GitHub Flavored Markdown:

;; A [GitHub Flavored Markdown][GFM] (GFM) mode, `gfm-mode', is also
;; available.  The GitHub implementation of differs slightly from
;; standard Markdown.  The most important differences are that
;; newlines are significant, triggering hard line breaks, and that
;; underscores inside of words (e.g., variable names) need not be
;; escaped.  As such, `gfm-mode' turns off `auto-fill-mode' and turns
;; on `visual-line-mode' (or `longlines-mode' if `visual-line-mode' is
;; not available).  Underscores inside of words (such as
;; test_variable) will not trigger emphasis.
;;
;; Wiki links in this mode will be treated as on GitHub, with hyphens
;; replacing spaces in filenames and where the first letter of the
;; filename capitalized.  For example, `[[wiki link]]' will map to a
;; file named `Wiki-link` with the same extension as the current file.
;;
;; GFM code blocks, with optional programming language keywords, will
;; be highlighted.  They can be inserted with `C-c C-s P`.  If there
;; is an active region, the text in the region will be placed inside
;; the code block.  You will be prompted for the name of the language,
;; but may press enter to continue without naming a language.
```

Comment: markdown-mode is definitely nice, but does it do anything about tables? The question specifically singled that bit out.